# Can I rename an SSAS tabular model without breaking the SSRS reports that use it

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, analysisservices

I have made a spelling error in the name of my SSAS tabular model. I'd like to fix the model name and the name of the deployed analysis server database. The problem is, I already have about 60 SSRS reports that use this database as their data source. I don't want to have to go into each report and change the data source name. Is there any way I can use some kind of alias (or other) functionality to be able to do this change without breaking all my reports?

I have seen that there are many solutions for renaming columns and tables within the tabular model, but I can't find any solutions for renaming the tabular model itself, and its associated analysis server database, without breaking the SSRS reports that use the database.

I know that the reports are just referencing the database, and not necessarily the model, so I could rename the model without breaking the reports (I know how to rename the model), as long as the database name is not changed. This would be a half-solution. I need to also be able to rename the database that the tabular model generates. So I've also looked for database alias options and honestly don't know what I'm reading or whether the ideas would work for this situation.

If anyone has any ideas, or has done this before, any help would be much appreciated.